# Represent long numbers in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, variables, numbers

I am doing a algorithm for wireless comunications in Matlab that calculates the lost and the deviation of a logarithmic model when calculating the looses at different distances.

Everything works fine, this is my function: 
d0 = distance of reference (always the same)
nombre = this is for a .mat file that has a matrix 250x2 in where the first column have the distances (from where I took the different values) and the second column has the values
Lfs2 = this is the lost where the distance is d0

```
Lfs2 = -20*log10((4*pi*d0)/((299792458)/(freq*10^6)));
```

I just made the algorithm and everything works fine for my 250x2 matrix, but just for testing purposes I made a bluetooth signal model with 4246x2 matrix, but when I do my algorithm with this value, my n (lost factor) is correctly calculate, but my desv factor isn't.. this is because the number is too big that is INF

```
    function [ n , desv ] = perd_desv(d0, Lfs2, nombre)
    %UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
    %   Detailed explanation goes here

    % Comprobamos que Pld0 es una perdida y no una atenuación
    if Lfs2>0
        Lfs2 = -Lfs2;
    end
    Lfs2;

    %Nombre = 'Practica28.mat';
    load(nombre);


    medida = Pl(:,2);
    distancia = Pl(:,1);

    % Calculo la n %
    syms n;
    p = 0;
    for i=1:size(medida,1)
        p = p + (medida(i)-(-Lfs2)-10*n*log10(distancia(i)/d0))^2;
    end
    perdida = double(solve(diff(p)));
    n = sprintf('%.2f',perdida);

    % Calculo de la desv
    w = 0;
    for i=1:size(medida,1)
        w = w + (1/size(medida,1))*(medida(i)-(Lfs2)-10*perdida*log10(distancia(i)/d0))^2;
    end
    w = 0;
for i=1:size(medida,1)
    w = w + (1/size(medida,1))*(medida(i)-(-Lfs2)-10*perdida*log10(distancia(i)/d0))^2;
end
desv = sprintf('%.2f',double(sqrt(w)));
```

The thing is..I know that in Matlab there is symsum for sum of series..but I can't see how to define this algorithm using symsum.. and I don't know how can I represent that number to fit in my variable..

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

One advice (that is *not* to be followed when you require high-speed calculations that will surely not fail) is to "unwind" your logarithms. Due to the properties of logarithms, you can easily express:

log(*a*/*b*) = log(*a*)−log(*b*)

for cases when *a* and *b* fit in the `double` range, but *a*/*b* doesn't. This is a guess (because you didn't offer a hint about the orders of magnitudes for `medida` and `distancia` relative to `d0`).

So, try writing code like:

```
% constants below may be calculated just once
Lfs2 = -20*(log10(4*pi*d0) - log10(299792458) + 6 + log10(freq))
```

or:

```
w = w + (1/size(medida,1))*(                      ...
     medida(i)                                    ...
   - Lfs2                                         ...
   - 10*perdida*(log10(distancia(i)) - log10(d0)) ...
)^2;
```

Also, verify if `size(medida,1)` isn't zero sometimes (there's no hint how is calculated, excepting that is the first column of some matrix).

Comment: How about the other points? Do you always have the `size(medida,1)` bigger than zero? Just add a conditional breakpoint on that to see if that is theo problem.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, with that property I can calculate the Lfs2 faster..but this is just an upgrade, because Lfs2 its a factor that you need to calculate once. I did not post the entire code for not to be so boring..but you are right. I have a matrix(2426x2) that in the first column has the distance and in the second column has the value of the power of the signal. I guess maybe something more is wrong. what its really annoying is that when you use my algorithm with a shorter matrix (250x2)my algorithm is very accurate(not so fast..but that is not a problem now) thank u for your answer

Comment: In your code, there are two potential sources of "infinity" from divisions: either `1/size(medida,1)` is `1/0`, or `distancia(i)/d0`. Now, **are you sure** that you eliminated all these possible causes? For example, if you calculate `x = distancia/d0` and examine the variable `x`, do you have infinities over there?